# Indirect referencing in Korn Shell

Tags: arrays, shell, ksh

How can i refer an indirect variable in the korn shell

Suppose i've an Variable

```
FLAG_1=0
```

and i want this variable value to changed from the array that i've set

```
set -A Flags_array
Flags_array[0]=? #how to achieve this here
```

For example if i try

```
Flags_array[0]=$FLAG_1 # this won't work as this assign the value
```

I tried doing something like this

```
Flags_array[0]=FLAG_1
echo ${Flags_array[0]}
```

But this gives output `FLAG_1`

I tried using `nameref` but it's giving me error

```
$ nameref Flags_array[0]=FLAG_1
ksh: nameref:  not found
```

Please tell me what is proper way to achieving this ?
because what i want to do is later 
if i write `Flags_array[0]=10` the `value of FLAG_1 becomes 10`

Answer (score 0):

i just tried it on my console, and it seems that you are using an invalid option for set.... try using small a instead of capital:

```
set -a Flags_array
```

just did it like this in my console and worked:

```
set -a array
number=5
array[0]= $number
echo $array[0]   --------> from which i got result : 5[0]
```

also just to know for future reference, you dont need the curly brackets `{}`, these you use only if you are calling a variable in a place were actual data would be expected (sorry for the expression), for example here you would need them:

```
were e.g. random=5

sed "${random}s/^.*$/1/" test.txt
```

Hope this clears things for you.. :)

Comment: capital A also works. + without curly bracket the result you have got is not a valid result `result : 5[0]` and here i don't seek the result the question is about indirect referencing

Comment: man what to tell you, on my machine which is connected on private server it works with small a, on capital i get an error amd also it works fine on the results, are you sure you are running ksh????